# Azure Devops + JMeter - Always generate html report?

Tags: azure, jmeter, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have an JMeter script which:

- Consumes sitemap.xml for my site
- Requests all pages

I have specified a custom user.properties file which has this line within it:

`jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.property.output_dir=report`

I am attempting to schedule this to run nightly with Azure DevOps JMeter task (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=784929).

My question is:  How can I force the user.properties file to *always* generate an HTML report of the outcome?  I want to store this as a build artifact and schedule this to run nightly.  As of right now, it appears that the Azure Build job does not allow me to pass command line parameters to JMeter nor does it allow me to specify that I want an HTML report generated.  Is there another way to force the HTML report to generate?

Answer (score 0):

Using VSTS, it is not possible and anyway it will be [discontinued](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/load-test/overview?view=azure-devops) by Microsoft.

I would suggest using [Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714591/vsts-maven-build-failaure-forbidden/47065054#47065054) and [jmeter-maven-plugin](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/shift-left-performance-tests-jmeter-maven/).

The goal will be:

> mvn clean verify